# "resolved attribute(s) missing" when performing join on pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two pySpark dataframe:

```
> df_lag_pre.columns
['date','sku','name','country','ccy_code','quantity','usd_price','usd_lag','lag_quantity']

> df_unmatched.columns
['alt_sku', 'alt_lag_quantity', 'country', 'ccy_code', 'name', 'usd_price']
```

Now I want to join them on common columns, so I try the following:

```
> df_lag_pre.join(df_unmatched, on=['name','country','ccy_code','usd_price'])
```

And I get the following error message:

```
AnalysisException: u'resolved attribute(s) price#3424 missing from country#3443,month#801,price#808,category#803,subcategory#804,page#805,date#280,link#809,name#806,quantity#807,ccy_code#3439,sku#3004,day#802 in operator !EvaluatePython PythonUDF#<lambda>(ccy_code#3439,price#3424), pythonUDF#811: string;'
```

Some of the columns that show up on this error, such as price, were part of another dataframe from which `df_lag` was built from. I can't find any info on how to interpret this message, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is source of `!EvaluatePython PythonUDF`? Could you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: It seems there is an issue in lineage of df_lag_pre. If you could provide the complete set of transformations, we could be able to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform join this way in pyspark, Please see if this is useful for you:

```
df_lag_pre.alias("df1")
df_unmatched.alias("df2")
join_both = df1.join(df2, (col("df1.name") == col("df2.name")) & (col("df1.country") == col("df2.country")) & (col("df1.ccy_code") == col("df2.ccy_code")) & (col("df1.usd_price") == col("df2.usd_price")), 'inner')
```

Update: If you are getting col not defined error, please use below import

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

Comment: You can use : from pyspark.sql.functions import col and df1 is the alias name. No need to define and df_lag_pre and df_unmatched already defined. Hope this will help!