# Java Spark : Spark Bug Workaround for Datasets Joining with unknow Join Column Names

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.3.1 with Java.

I have encountered what (I think), is [this known bug of Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14948).

Here is my code :

```
public Dataset<Row> compute(Dataset<Row> df1, Dataset<Row> df2, List<String> columns){
    Seq<String> columns_seq = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(columns.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();

    final Dataset<Row> join = df1.join(df2, columns_seq);

    join.show()

    join.withColumn("newColumn", abs(col("value1").minus(col("value2")))).show();

    return join;
}
```

I call my code like this :

```
Dataset<Row> myNewDF = compute(MyDataset1, MyDataset2, Arrays.asList("field1","field2","field3","field4"));
```

Note : MyDataset1 and MyDataset2 are two datasets that come from the same Dataset MyDataset0 with multiple different transformations.

On the `join.show()` line, I get the following error :

```
2018-08-03 18:48:43 - ERROR main Logging$class -  -  - failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 235, Column 21: Expression "project_isNull_2" is not an rvalue
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 235, Column 21: Expression "project_isNull_2" is not an rvalue
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:11821)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.toRvalueOrCompileException(UnitCompiler.java:7170)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.getConstantValue2(UnitCompiler.java:5332)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$9400(UnitCompiler.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$13$1.visitAmbiguousName(UnitCompiler.java:5287)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Java$AmbiguousName.accept(Java.java:4053)
    ...

2018-08-03 18:48:47 - WARN main Logging$class -  -  - Whole-stage codegen disabled for plan (id=7):
```

But it does not stop the execution and still displays the content of the dataset.

Then, on the line `join.withColumn("newColumn", abs(col("value1").minus(col("value2")))).show();`

I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) 'value2,'value1 missing from field6#16,field7#3,field8#108,field5#0,field9#4,field10#28,field11#323,value1#298,field12#131,day#52,field3#119,value2#22,field2#35,field1#43,field4#144 in operator 'Project [field1#43, field2#35, field3#119, field4#144, field5#0, field6#16, value2#22, field7#3, field9#4, field10#28, day#52, field8#108, field12#131, value1#298, field11#323, abs(('value1 - 'value2)) AS newColumn#2579]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: value2,value1. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
'Project [field1#43, field2#35, field3#119, field4#144, field5#0, field6#16, value2#22, field7#3, field9#4, field10#28, day#52, field8#108, field12#131, value1#298, field11#323, abs(('value1 - 'value2)) AS newColumn#2579]
+- AnalysisBarrier
...
```

This error end the program.

The workaround proposed Mijung Kim on the Jira Issue is to create a Dataset clone thanks to toDF(Columns). But in my case, where the column names used for the join are not known in advance (I only have a List), I can't use this workaround.

Is there another way to get around this very annoying bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to call this method:

```
private static Dataset<Row> cloneDataset(Dataset<Row> ds) {
    List<Column> filterColumns = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> filterColumnsNames = new ArrayList<>();
    scala.collection.Iterator<StructField> it = ds.exprEnc().schema().toIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String columnName = it.next().name();
        filterColumns.add(ds.col(columnName));
        filterColumnsNames.add(columnName);
    }
    ds = ds.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(filterColumns).seq()).toDF(scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(filterColumnsNames.iterator()).asScala().toSeq());
    return ds;
}
```

on both datasets just before the join like this :

```
df1 = cloneDataset(df1);
df2 = cloneDataset(df2);
final Dataset<Row> join = df1.join(df2, columns_seq);
// or ( based on Nakeuh comment )
final Dataset<Row> join = cloneDataset(df1.join(df2, columns_seq));
```

Comment: Your solution do not work in my case, but based on your cloneDataset function, I did : final Dataset<Row> join = cloneDataset(df1.join(df2, columns_seq));
And it work well.

Comment: @Nakeuh: indeed your suggestion works. Still trying to understand what's going on though.

Comment: @Abdenaceur Lichiheb: do you have reference to a Spark issue ?

Comment: You can find Spark issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713290/how-to-resolve-the-analysisexception-resolved-attributes-in-spark/